# Terraform: dynamically create list of resources

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, custom-lists

Due to some prior decisions, there is a script that creates ALBs and a completely separate one to setup alarms for each ALB created (odd, but I can't change this).

I could hard code a list of all the ALBs and iterate thru them, ie:

> albs = ['a', 'b']

I know how to iterate thru a list with a "for_each".

What I need is to build the list dynamically so I don't have to manually maintain the list. I know I can get a list of ALBs using:

> terraform state list [options]   ## https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/list.html

but that doesn't really help (sure, I can pipe that to a file and iterate through the lines in the file and pass them as parameters - but that is ugly as sin)

How do I dynamically build the list with all my ALBs? Something like:

> albs = state_list([options])

Thanks! Using AWS.

Comment: Why would you not setup alarms at the same time you create the ALB if every ALB needs it?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR - long story. Short version: I'm new in this company and that decision was done before me. Lets see what the future holds. Gotta do this right now.

Comment: What alarms are you creating? Or more precisely, what do you need returning? A list of ALB names? Or ARNs? Or something else? All of them in a specific region? Or some form of filter?

Comment: List of ALB names (w/ the name I can get the ARN). Yes, in a specific region and if we can filter it to return ALB w/ a specific prefix it would be great. bonus: Find the Target groups for 1 ALB. The alarms I'm creating is to watch for 4xx, 5xx, response time errors.